# Naming classes that query a database

Tags: dao, naming

I know about the DAO pattern, but a DAO is meant for persisting entities, not for performing complex queries. People also often suggest that DAOs only query a single table, using multiple DAOs at the service layer to construct a complete entity.

But what about more complex queries, like a query that searches for specific entities and returns a list of Ids? How do i name classes that perform this kind of queries? I have seen classes that were named something like `QueryManager` which is horribly generic.

Is there a pattern for this kind of query-classes, or should i just name them something like `EntitySearcher` (where entity would be replaced by the actual entities name)?

Comment: You mean like CustomerRepository?

Comment: Shouldn't a repository leverage some other class to find the Ids and then load them using a Dao?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33109/repository-service-design-pattern might be a good read